# Kernel recompiled with same config but: cpufreq: no nforce2 chipset error

Tags: linux-kernel

I need to compile an old kernel 2.6.23 (downloaded from linuxkernels.com) in order to use it with a real time patch (it's a long story...), I installed ubuntu 10.04 which has a kernel 2.6.32-43-generic-pae.
I decided to simple copy ubuntu configuration:

```
cp cp /boot/config-2.6.32-43-generic-pae /usr/src/linux-2.6.23/.config
```

I recompile the kernel:

```
make menuconfig 
make
make install
make modules_install
mkinitramfs -o /boot/initrd.img-2.6.23-MYVER 2.6.23-MYVER
```

note that in the config I make this edit: I remove the module versioning support under loadable modules section. (this step is required by the patch).

At start, I get the title error:

```
cpufreq: no nforce2 chipset error
```

how it possible, since I copied a working configuration? Maybe is because of that only flag I disable?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure, but when I copy an existing .config, I run "make oldconfig" first to make sure I'm all sync'd up. Then I run make menuconfig if I want to interactively review/change any settings.

Comment: the sources for the Ubuntu kernel are heavily patched so a vanilla kernel it's different from a kernel for Ubuntu, you can't compile a vanilla kernel for Ubuntu without patching it or without downloading the source from Ubuntu/Canonical